# Отображение границ доверительного интервала на графике в python

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, график

Есть две генеральные совокупности одинакового размера и почти разными в ней значениями.
Первая расположена по ссылке - https://apmonitor.com/che263/uploads/Main/stats_data.txt
Вторая на моём пк - [dataset_99](https://cloud.mail.ru/public/5phG/4fSshYs3Z)
Я отобразил их на графике рассеивания и рассчитал линию регрессии и границы доверительного интервала, но границы доверительного интервала у первой совокупности выглядят так
[image: -],
а у второй так

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
У любой сгенерированной мною совокупности в Ecxel и сохранённой в csv формате границы доверительного интервала выглядят как на втором рисунке.
Подскажите почему так происходит?

Мой код:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy import stats
from scipy.stats import norm
import math

params = {'legend.fontsize': 'x-large',
          'figure.figsize': (8,8),
          'axes.labelsize': 'xx-large',
          'axes.titlesize': 'xx-large',
          'xtick.labelsize': 'x-large',
          'ytick.labelsize': 'x-large'}
plt.rcParams.update(params)

#url = 'https://apmonitor.com/che263/uploads/Main/stats_data.txt'
#df = pd.read_csv(url)
#x = df['x'].values
#y = df['y'].values
#print("x: \n", sorted(x), "\n\ny: \n", sorted(y))

df = pd.read_csv("dataset_99.csv", sep = ";", header = None)
x = df[0].values
y = df[1].values
print("Мощность двигателя (x): \n", sorted(x), "\n\nВремя разгона (y): \n", sorted(y))
df.shape

# Объём выборок
Nx = len(x)
Ny = len(y)
print("Объём выборки x: ", Nx,
      "\nОбъём выборки y: ", Ny)

# Среднее выборочное значение переменных x и y
x_srednee = np.mean(x)
y_srednee = np.mean(y)
print("\nВыборочное среднее значение переменной x: ", x_srednee,
      "\nВыборочное среднее значение переменной y: ", y_srednee)

# Среднее квадратическое отколнение переменных x и y
Sx = np.std(x)
Sy = np.std(y)
print("\nСреднее квадратическое отколнение переменной x: ", Sx,
      "\nСреднее квадратическое отколнение переменной y: ", Sy)

# Расчёт: - Коэффициента корреляции;
#         - Оценок параметров парвной линейно регерссии
#         - Характеристик оценки регрессии
slope, intercept, r_value, p_value, std_err = stats.linregress(x, y)
print("Коэффициент корреляции: ", r_value, # r_value - Коэффициент корреляции - Rxy
      "\n\nКоэффициент регрессии: ", slope, # slope - Коэффициент регрессии - b
      "\nСвободный член регрессии: ", intercept, # intercept - Свободный член регрессии - a
      "\n\nСтандартная ошибка регрессии: ", std_err, # std_err - Стандартная ошибка регрессии - Se
      "\nКоэффициент детерминации: ", r_value**2) # R-squared - Коэффициент детерминации - R^2

predict = [slope * xi + intercept for xi in x] # Прогнозируемое значение зависимой переменной

# Доверительная вероятность
dov_ver = 0.95

# Расчёт границ доверительного интервала для линии регрессии
Rd = 1 - dov_ver # Уровень значимости
Numerator_X = (x - x_srednee)**2 # Числитель
Denominator_X = np.sum(Numerator_X) # Знаменатель
q = norm.ppf(1 - Rd/2, Nx - 2) # Квантиль распределения Стьюдента

Right_part = q * std_err * (1/Nx + Numerator_X/Denominator_X) # Правая часть выражения

Lower_limit = predict + Right_part # Нижняя граница
Upper_limit = predict - Right_part # Верхняя граница

# График рассеивания
plt.plot(x, predict,"r-", linewidth=2, label="Линия регрессии")
plt.plot(x, Lower_limit, c="orange", linewidth=2, label="Границы доверительного инетрвала")
plt.plot(x, Upper_limit, c="orange", linewidth=2)
plt.plot(x, y, 'o', markersize=8, label="Мощность двигателя")
plt.title("График рассеивания")
plt.xlabel("x")
plt.ylabel("y")
plt.grid(True)
plt.legend(loc="upper right")
plt.show()
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59747610/5741205

Comment: Всё равно получается почти тоже самое - https://cloud.mail.ru/public/3bEC/5ekZJYyVh

Comment: На первом рисунке - все понятно, нарисованы границы доверительного интервала. А на втором рисунке тем-же цветом обозначены некоторые области. Так мы о чем -  о границе, которая может быть только линией, или о области?